# Planck theory of discrete energy of photons and electromagnetic spectrum

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, frequency, wavelength, discrete

Planck said that "energy of photon is quantized. That means energy of a photon cannot be any random value but a certain values only".

If this is true how electromagnetic spectrum is continuous. For example, we know that spectrum of visible light is continuous but this implies that visible light can have all frequencies between red and violet and this again implies that photons can have all energy values between energy of red light and energy of violet light. But isn't contradictory to Planck's theory that energy of photon can only take discrete values.

Comment: related   https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/508452/black-body-radiation-and-line-spectra/508484#508484

Answer (score 0):

EM radiation is quantised, and the quanta are photons. However, photons can have any frequency. Their energy is given by E=hf, where f is the frequency and h is Planck's constant.

In other words, a wave of EM radiation can be created with any frequency, but the energy in the wave has to be multiples of hf.

Comment: This answer begs the question as the OP was asking how the photon can have discrete values because visible light is continuous, and @Marco answers that EM radiation is continuous. Clarification is needed.